# process em python

Tags: python

Estou tentando alterar uma variavel externa dentro de um process mas não está funcionando.
Criei uma classe simples de testes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
class Classe():
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    self.variavel="antes"
    self.p = Process(target=self.f, args=(self.variavel,))

  def f(self, variavel2):
    variavel2="depois"
  def g(self):
    self.p.start()
    self.p.join()
    print self.variavel



teste=Classe()
teste.g()
```

Mas ao executar isso, ele imprime o valor antigo da variavel, alguem sabe como faço pra acessar uma variavel normal dentro do processo, tentei usar self.variavel mas não deu certo também.

Answer (score 4):

Um pouco mais complexo do que se pode pensar à partida. [Isto (*Sharing state between processes*)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) quando é com inteiros é um pouco mais simples do que com strings. EX com inteiros:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

class Classe():

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.variavel=Value('i', 0)
        self.p = Process(target=self.f, args=())

    def f(self):
        self.variavel.value = 2

    def g(self):
        self.p.start()
        self.p.join()

    def get_var(self):
        return self.variavel.value
```

Exemplo com strings (creio que seja isto que quer) temos de importar [c_char_p de ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) para este caso:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Manager
from ctypes import c_char_p

class Classe():

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        manager = Manager()
        self.variavel=manager.Value(c_char_p, "antes")
        self.p = Process(target=self.f, args=())

    def f(self):
        self.variavel.value = "depois"

    def g(self):
        self.p.start()
        self.p.join()

    def get_var(self):
        return self.variavel.value
```

Uso para os dois casos apresentados em cima:

```
teste=Classe()
print(teste.get_var())
teste.g()
print(teste.get_var())
```

Comment: Mas assim nao resolve meu problema... Eu preciso que o process edite a variavel da classe, e que ela fique com o novo valor, e isso nao está acontecendo

Comment: https://s31.postimg.org/jx87yh14r/teste.png
Olha só o teste no terminal, coloquei a classe h para que mostre a variavel depois de ter sido editada pelo process
Tentei inclusive esperar e executar teste.h() varis vezes depois e ele ainda imprime antes.

Comment: Eu sei estou a testar também

Comment: Feito em cima @MegaAnim

Comment: Editei para que `Process` seja chamado no init, como você tinha na pergunta

Comment: Olha, acho que assim nao da pra fazer, pois eu quero criar um processo no meu software que estou criando, e as variaveis que preciso editar precisam ser seu tipo certo, string, e tal, nao podem ser manager, pois elas são usadas em todo o programa...
Vou explicar melhor o que eu preciso, eu tenho uma função:
def funcaoA(self): faço minha função << preciso que tudo que for executado nessa função seja executado em segundo plano num processo diferente para deixar o programa mais leve... Esse foi o motivo que resolvi procurar como fazer multiprocessing

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41530/discussion-between-miguel-and-mega-anim).

Comment: Editei em cima. Assim tem acesso à variavel em todo o programa

Comment: No fundo a variável não é do tipo manager, self.variavel.value é int ou string nos exemplos que lhe dei, self.variavel é que é manager